# MouseEvents for instantiated prefab not called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

After some hours of research i will finally post here :)

My problem is that I am not able to receive any MouseEvents on newly instantiated prefabs unless i modify them in any way in the unity editor while the game is running. I've already checked possible issues with UI but I can exclude that.

Prefab looks like that:

[image]

---

Script on the Prefab (EntityHandler deriving from MonoBehaviour):

[image]

---

Is there anything the internet didnt tell me yet or am I just blind?
Any suggestions appreciated :)

Comment: Avoid the OnMouseXXX functions. Use new eventsystem or raycast for this. See duplicate for more info. Since this is a 2D collider, see **7**.

Comment: God bless you! Thanks alot